# .htaccess redirect http > https with 301 redirects

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect, https

I have recently had an SSL certificate installed and now my entire website uses it, without errors.  I had set up a redirect from http to https but realised it was using a 302 redirect.  I currently use the following code which uses a 301 redirect.

Is this correct?  Can I remove any part of this, or should I change any part of this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Thank you for checking.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your code is weird, why you redirect on HTTP all and after that on https in second part :) ?

Here is my example, it is similar to yours but I don't need to change every time domain name for example if you use the same pattern on different servers + this will redirect all traffic from http to https

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\d+.BIN_AUTOSSL_CHECK_PL__.\w+.tmp$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.well-known/acme-challenge/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+..+.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

The `RewriteCond %{HTTPS}` on portion may not work for all web servers. My webhost requires `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL}` on, for instance.

Comment: This shows up as a 302 redirect.  I need it to be a 301 (SEO)